# What is good reading for an advanced level Entity Framework 4.1 refresher?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I last used EF at v1, and without going into too much depth. Code-first has passed me by, mainly, and I am now embarking on a cutting edge greenfield project, and when I went to get the latest EF, I see we are now on 4.1.

What do you recommend I could read, such as tutorials etc. to help me get back into touch with EF?

Comment: EF didn't have a v3. It had a v1, then a v4, then a v4.1. And a v4.2.

Comment: Whatever the last version was I used. I assumed 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julie Lerman's [Programming Entity Framework 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004PLG1OO) and her new book [Programming Entity Framework: Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312942)
 are nice books.

I havent read the second book but reviews are good. Its about 200 pages and should be a quick read on Code first.

Answer (score 0):

Julie/Rowan's new book is great, you can also check out the blogs for some of the key individuals - Arthur (http://blog.oneunicorn.com/) is an influential and vocal dev on the team and Rowan (http://romiller.com/) is one of the PMs that blogs a lot.  Diego is another PM that blogs at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/ and the team blog is the first candidate for posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/.  Things have changed pretty substantially overall and most people will be happy to know that using EF is easier than ever.